# How do i replace line in text file?

Tags: tcl

How can i replace a specific line in text file in Tcl for example:

`a.txt` contains:

```
John
Elton
```

and I need to replace the contents to `b.txt` which contains:

```
John
Belushi
```

In Bash, I know that I can use: `sed '2s/.*/Belushi/' a.txt > b.txt`. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many ways. If you want to use the same `sed` command, you can very well do it with the `exec` command

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
exec sed {2s/.*/Belushi/} a.txt > b.txt
```

The reason why we quoted this with the braces instead of single quotes is to prevent any substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

The pure Tcl way of doing the replacement is this:

```
# Read the lines into a Tcl list
set f [open "a.txt"]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Do the replacement
lset lines 1 "Belushi"

# Write the lines back out
set f [open "b.txt" w]
puts -nonewline $f [join $lines "\n"]
close $f
```

The only vaguely tricky bit is that you need `-nonewline` or you'll get an extra newline from the `puts`; we're supplying all the newlines that we want it to produce already.